# Adding additional column in table leads to high performance issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, performance, entity-framework, oracle11g

I am facing a strange issue in one of our production site

In one of our sites we do have an existing table , and because of some new features we just added a new column into the table. Everything works fine until it went to production. In production site we are facing huge performance issues in this page, that is also not consistent. Sometimes the page get loaded with in milliseconds and sometimes it takes minutes to load.

We are not facing any issues in other environments like QA and Dev. It seems like especially the calls which is getting data from the above mentioned table is getting delayed.

We are using Oracle as the Back end database.

Asp.Net MVC as framework

Entity framework Database first approach as ORM

Note : I have created another table in prod with same columns and copy pasted the data and dropped old table, that also doesn't help.

Below is the DDL of my table

```
CREATE TABLE "XYZ_OURSCHEMA"."SAMPLETABLE" 
   (    "CODE" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COLUMN1" VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COLUMN2" NUMBER(12,2), 
    "COLUMN3" NUMBER(12,2), 
    "COLUMN4" CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N', 
    "COLUMN5" NUMBER(12,2), 
    "COLUMN6" CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N', 
    "COLUMN7" VARCHAR2(300), 
    "COLUMN8" DATE, 
    "COLUMN9" DATE, 
    "COLUMN10" VARCHAR2(200), 
    "COLUMN11" DATE, 
    "COLUMN12" VARCHAR2(200), 
    "COLUMN13" NUMBER(12,2), 
     CONSTRAINT "SAMPLETABLE_PRI" PRIMARY KEY ("CODE", "COLUMN1")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 131072 NEXT 131072 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "OURSCHEMA_INDEX"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 0 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 131072 NEXT 131072 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "OURSCHEMA_DATA" ;
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "XYZ_OURSCHEMA"."SAMPLETABLE_PRI" ON "XYZ_OURSCHEMA"."SAMPLETABLE_TBL" ("CODE", "COLUMN1") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 131072 NEXT 131072 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "OURSCHEMA_INDEX" ;
  CREATE INDEX "XYZ_OURSCHEMA"."SAMPLETABLE_COLUMN1_IDX" ON "XYZ_OURSCHEMA"."SAMPLETABLE_TBL" ("COLUMN1") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 131072 NEXT 131072 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "OURSCHEMA_INDEX" ;
  ALTER TABLE "XYZ_OURSCHEMA"."SAMPLETABLE_TBL" ADD CONSTRAINT "SAMPLETABLE_PRI" PRIMARY KEY ("CODE", "COLUMN1")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 131072 NEXT 131072 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "OURSCHEMA_INDEX"  ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "XYZ_OURSCHEMA"."SAMPLETABLE_TBL" MODIFY ("COLUMN1" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "XYZ_OURSCHEMA"."SAMPLETABLE_TBL" MODIFY ("CODE" NOT NULL ENABLE);
```

Is there any idea why this happen ? Or is there anything that can be changed or modified for getting out of this issue ?

Comment: Try to gather statistics on the table.

Comment: @Littlefoot sure I have request our DBA to get the statistics . But my doubt is why its not consistent , some times it works with in milliseconds and some times it takes minutes , And i have tried to run the query from PL SQL and it works as expected all the time. Issue is only when we try to open the page from website

Comment: If there's no problem in the database (apparently, it is not, as your test shows that it behaves OK all the time), then the problem is somewhere else. Network issues, perhaps?

Comment: @Littlefoot ok , but if its network issues then it should happen with all the calls in the page right ? we do have different ajax calls in the same page and all other calls are getting completed , only this one takes too long time

Comment: This question is too vague to answer. All you can do is try to figure out (1) why the query runs slow in Production and not in QA and (2) why the query only runs slow some times. I suspect the answer to both questions is **data volumes**. Does your application have some instrumentation (trace/logging)? which could help you with the diagnosis?

Comment: @APC Got your point. And we dont have much data in production now number of rows are lesser than 10 K . The fact is like the issue is coming only after adding a new column , before it was working ok. This one is an old application so we dont have logging enabled , planning to create a logging for the same , so that we will get to know where its lagging

Comment: Was COLUMN13 the column you added?

Comment: @APC yes its newly added column.